# Inline Validation is not working

Tags: javascript, jsp

[image]

In this web page I applied online validation But it is not working.

In Jsp code:

```
  <tr><td><label style="color: red;">*</label>Book No</td>
    <td><input type="text"                                                                                 size="20"                                            name="book_no"                                                 
    id="book_no"                          onchange="changeImg()"/></td>
    <td><img id="right" height="20px" src="right.jpg" style="display:none"/> 
    <img id="wrong" height="20px" src="wrong.jpg" style="display:none"/></td>
    </tr>

Inside Javascript page:
   function changeImg(){
if(document.getElementById('book_no').value!=""){
    document.getElementById('right').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('wrong').style.display="none";

 }
else{
    document.getElementById('right').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('wrong').style.display="block";

    }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
onchange="changeImg()"
```

with

```
onchange="this.changeImg()"
```

The reason this works is because **this** is set to the **window** object where your function exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
      //javascript code
function ValidateForm()
        {   
           if(document .getElementById("<%=book_name.ClientID %>").value=="")
            {
                alert("Please Enter book Name");
                book_name.focus();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
//aspcode
  <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm();" />
```